# Calculate the Martin-Metrics for packages

Tags: oop, architecture, uml, metrics

See for calculation: https://101.jqassistant.org/calculate-metrics/index.html

- Ca (afferent couplings):
  The number of classes outside this component that depend on classes within this component. In short: the number of incoming dependencies.
- Ce (efferent couplings)
  The number of classes inside this component that depends on classes outside this component. In short: the number of outgoing dependencies.

---

Given is the UML-Diagram of the car-simulation application. Every layer represents its own package.

[image: UML-Diagram]

Calculate the Martin-Metrics for the four packages.

[image: Result]

Apart from the initialization this is a correct example of a layered architecture. Therefore calculate the afferent and efferent coupling again, this time without the initialization package.

[image: Result]
Which number(s) give a hint, that these three packages may form a correctly layered architecture?

I wanted to know if my solution is correct and if I have calculated it correctly.

Comment: No idea, but the calls you placed along the classes aside the associations is wrong. Class diagrams do not model behavior. You could just _name_ the associations or place a note along with them to indicate their use. But that would just be bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to find dependencies in an UML diagram?

Direct dependencies are documented with dashed arrows.

Dependencies can also be deducted from associations (and aggregations and compositions):

- We cannot say anything when there is unspecified navigability and no association-end ownership:  the association could own the ends and manage the links.
- We can assume a dependency for navigable associations and owned association end (dot notation) : the association needs to know at least about the class at the arrow or dot end.
- We cannot say for sure anything for the reverse dependency in case of unspecified navigability in the opposite direction; it could be navigable or not. We could assume absence of dependency,  since nothing formally identifies a dependency here.

We assume that the diagram is comprehensive and does show all the relevant classes.

### Inventory of dependencies in your diagram and metrics

The inventory:

- `SensorBus` directly depends on `Dashboard`.  Note that the label of the dependency `notifies()` is very strange. Is it a usage dependency (i.e. an operation `notifies()` uses `Dashboard` as parameter, but from where does it get this parameter)?
- `Startup` in initialization depends on `Dashboard`, `SensorBus` and `Car`
- `Dashboard` in UI depends on `Locale`
- `SensorBus` in functional layer depends on `Sensor`, `Car`, as well as `Weather` and `Locale` which are in the same package
- `Car` in HW-layer depends on `Sensor` which is in the same package
- `Sensor` in HW-layer depends on `SensorType` which is in the same package

According to your definition, this leads us to:

```
                      Ca    Ce
----------------------------------
Initialization         0     3
UI                     2     1
Functional layer       2     3 !!
HW layer               2 !!  0
```

Yes: 2 classes outside the HW package depend on HW classes.
Yes: the functional layer, `SensorBus` depends on 3 external classes: `Car`, `Sensor` and `Dashboard`.

### Issues in your background material

The wording used in your linked document is ambiguous about *Ce*:

- "*The number of classes inside this component that depends on classes outside this component*" contradicts the second part of the definition, since it does not correspond to the "*outgoing flows*".
- The correct definition is more like "The number of classes in other packages that the classes in a package depend upon" (source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_package_metrics) and [this blog](https://www.entrofi.net/coupling-metrics-afferent-and-efferent-coupling/))

Moreover, there is an issue about the package level of the calculation:

- *Ca* and *Ce* are well defined for classes are easy to apply since you just count unique classes on one side or the other of dependencies.
- For components and packages should we still keep counting classes ?  Or should we work at an homogeneous level of packages, i.e. counting dependencies with other packages? Martin and most authors opts for classes. But this seems inconsistent:  if I have a package with one class exposing nested clases, dependencies would count the top-level class (since the nested class is just a detail of the enclosing class) whereas the same design with a package providing directly the same classes instead of nesting them would count more classes and higher Ca or Ce.

Comment: Could you explain me why `HW layer` has `Ca = 2` and not `Ca = 3`. Do I count `SensorBus` to `Car` and `Sensor` only once, or what is the reason?

Comment: @Mr.Hankey By definition we have to count the number of classes outside the HW component that depend on classes within. I count SensorBus (it’s only one class outside, even if it appears in two dependencies) and Startup. The ambiguity is the informal short definition which suggest to count dependencies instead of classes.  Why classes and not dependencies? Because Ca is  meant to quantify change propagation. E.g, if I change HW substantially, what might I have to change elsewhere.